# biopython's efetch only returns the first features from any database

Tags: python, biopython

Any idea why this code:

```
handle = Entrez.efetch(db="nuccore", 
         id=['556503834'], rettype="gb", 
         retmode="txt")
print(handle.read())
```

doesn't return the full features that are found [on the ncbi description](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nuccore/556503834)? Only the first feature is returned (I was aiming to get the CDS features).

I tried other databases to the same conclusion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change `rettype` by `"gbwithparts"`

```
from Bio import Entrez
Entrez.email = "your@mail.com" #put real mail

handle = Entrez.efetch(db="nuccore", id=['556503834'], 
                   rettype="gbwithparts", retmode="txt")
print(handle.read())
```

Note : It may take a few seconds